# Thymeleaf - How to render a code-example block

Tags: thymeleaf

Im building a custom internal developer guide / component gallery.

Current template:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  layout:decorate="~{layout-dev}"
>
  <head>
    <title>Dev | Buttons | Solid</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div layout:fragment="content">
      <th:block th:insert="~{dev/buttons/menu :: menu}"></th:block>
      <div class="space-y-2">
        <div>
          <button
            type="submit"
            class="my-css-class>
            Log in
          </button>

          <!-- Magic here -->
          <code>
            <button
              type="submit"
              class="my-css-class"
            >
              Log in
            </button>
          </code>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I render the button example as **plain text**. I don't want to manually change all HTML tags to `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

The result should be a nice code block like so:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use textarea tag to avoid manual replacing all the < and > signs like this .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  layout:decorate="~{layout-dev}">

<head>
  <title>Dev | Buttons | Solid</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div layout:fragment="content">
    <th:block th:insert="~{dev/buttons/menu :: menu}"></th:block>
    <div class="space-y-2">
      <div>
        <button type="submit" class="my-css-class">
          Log in
        </button>

        <br> <br>

        <!-- Magic here -->
        <textarea disabled style="width: 800px; height: 100px; ">

        <button type="submit" class="my-css-class">Log in</button>
        <button type="submit" class="my-css-class">button 2</button>
        <button type="submit" class="my-css-class">button 3</button>
        <button type="submit" class="my-css-class">button 4</button>
        </textarea>




      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Output Image
[image: Output Image]

Comment: Oh the textarea, didn't think of that! I'll try. A small issue would be not having dynamic height, but I think that's solvable